# javascript, new object recursively

Tags: javascript, object

On jsbin I tested to see if this will work:

```
var person = new Object();
person.anon = new Object();
person.anon.name = "Someone";
```

well yes. Next I tried to put it to work where I needed in my code:

```
let task = new Object();
task.assigned = new Object();
tasks.assigned.word = w_prepared[tasks[z].assigned].word;
```

and I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'word' of undefined
```

I tried various way of expressing, all failed. Perhaps I don't understand something fundamental here.

Could you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: perhaps `w_prepared[tasks[z].assigned].word` is `undefined`.However try `tasks.assigned["word"] = w_prepared[tasks[z].assigned].word`;

Comment: You misspelled `task` as `tasks`.

Comment: Protip: It's much easier to use object literals instead of the `new Object` constructor. You'd write `const task = {assigned: {word: …}};`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
task.assigned.word = ...
```

instead of

```
tasks.assigned.word = ...
```

Comment: Please just flag/vote to close misspelling questions as off-topic, don't answer them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was my mistake in typing.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't create object with name `tasks` yet. So that you cannot set property to an `undefined` object.